# Make form div side by side in bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

My form contains two div elements. I want to display these div's side by side. Which class should i use in bootstrap?

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">            
<label for="ClientID">Client Id</label>             
<div class="col-sm-4">
<input required type="text">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">            
<label for="ClientID">Employee Id</label>               
<div class="col-sm-4">
<input required type="text">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Check this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="ClientID" class="col-form-label">Client Id</label>
            <input required="" type="text">

        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="ClientID" class="col-form-label">Employee Id</label>
            <input required="" type="text">
        </div>
    </form>
```